# javascript undefined input value despite of writing in it

Tags: javascript, html

I have a strange problem: I am getting a undefined alert window by running this code. I looked up all the entrys here but I couldn't find a solution.

- I've checked, there is no identical id except this one
- running the php file the result of `var_dump($user_id)` shows the right value
- this is why I don't understand why the value in javascript is undefined all the time...

**HTML:**

```
<form action="?atn=surveyCode" method="post" class="form mg_top">

  <label id="entersID" for="usersID">Enter your prolific ID:</label>
  <input id="usersID" value="" type='text' class="form-control talign_center input" name="usersID">

  <button id="survey" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Go to questions</button>

</form>
```

**JavaScript:** every alert is returning "undefined". I never get in the else part. This is really strange. I've many parts like this in my code and they are working perfectly.

```
$("#survey").click(function(e){

    var prolific = $("usersID").val();
    alert(prolific);

    if(prolific==undefined){
        alert(prolific);

        $("#entersID").addClass("error-msg");
        $("#entersID").parent().addClass("has-error");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else{
        alert(prolific);

        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
    }

});
```

**PHP:**

```
private function surveyCode(){
    $userID = $_POST["usersID"];
    var_dump($userID); //shows a value
}
```

Please help me, maybe this is a silly bug but I can't find it....

Comment: You are missing `#`. it should be `$("#usersID").val();`

Comment: thanks a lot you saved my day :D. such a silly mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line into

```
var prolific = $("#usersID").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the "#" sign before the id selector like below :

```
var prolific = $("#usersID").val();
```